# Rename table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I want to rename a table. But I get an error when running the code. What is the correct code?

```
DECLARE @TABLE_NAME VARCHAR(100)

SET @TABLE_NAME = 'Employee_Destination'

IF EXISTS (SELECT NAME FROM SYS.tables WHERE NAME = @TABLE_NAME)
BEGIN
    EXEC sp_rename @TABLE_NAME, @TABLE_NAME += '_2'
END
```

This error message (SSMS):

> Incorrect syntax near @TABLE_NAME

This error message (SSIS Project) :

> [Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query "DECLARE @TABLE_NAME
> VARCHAR(100) DECLARE @TABLE_TE..." failed with the following error:
> "An error occurred while extracting the result into a variable of type
> (DBTYPE_I4)". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query,
> "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly,
> or connection not established correctly.

Note: I run this code in a SSIS project

Thank you.

Comment: What is the error? And please only ask one question per question, so move you concatenation question to a new question.

Comment: i just edited it

Comment: `@TABLE_NAME += '_2'` That's not valid. Create a separate variable and concatenate the strings, `DECLARE @NEW_TABLE_NAME nvarchar(128); SET @NEW_TABLE_NAME = @TABLE_NAME + N'_2'; `

Comment: You can't do this `@TABLE_NAME += '_2'` parameters passed into `EXEC` must be static i.e with no computations, so you need to assign everything before you call `EXEC`.

Comment: Ohhh, so I have to declare @TABLE_RENAME, right?

Comment: Yep. Declare and assign the new value *before* using the variable in `exec`

Comment: This has a certain code smell to it. Since you said this is an SSIS package I have the feeling that you are renaming tables regularly. This is very rarely a good idea and is usually an indication of something that went a bit left of center in the design phase.